# Use 'level' property with plotly.express treemap

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I am currently creating a treemap using plotly.express. To automatically generate and save parts of the plot I want to use the 'level' property that is documented in the plotly.graph_objects.Treemap (https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Treemap.html). However this can not be used when initializing the plotly.express version (https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.treemap.html). Is there any easy way to fix this?
The other option would be to always filter the dataframe beforehand.

Thank you in advance,

Sören